# SUPEE 8788 patch installation error on Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0
I am trying to install all the patches in my site and i installed all the patches but when i am trying to install patch `SUPEE 8788 for magento ver. 1.8.1.0` , it shows error. I seached the google stuff, still not able to solve this issue.

Please find below error:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Gallery/Content.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Content/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Media/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Category/Tree.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Serialized.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 91.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Media/UploaderController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/Model/Api/Client.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Url.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Encryption.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Book.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Info/Checkmo.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Resource/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Payment/Transaction.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote/Payment.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Recurring/Profile.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Multiple.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Block/Single.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Helper/File.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Abstract.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Browsebutton.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Misc.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/Model/Config/Uploader.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Uploader/etc/jstranslator.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl/International.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/system.xml
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Block/Adminhtml/Mobile/Edit/Tab/Design/Images.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/Adminhtml/MobileController.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/cms/browser/content/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/product/edit/downloadable/samples.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design.phtml
checking file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Media.csv
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Uploader.csv
checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 372.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file js/lib/uploader/flow.min.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js
checking file js/lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/product.js
checking file js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js
checking file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
checking file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
checking file skin/adminhtml/default/default/xmlconnect/boxes.css

Done
```

If anyone have any idea, please help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: If anyone have any idea, then please update

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: i have same issue too, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem applying `SUPEE 8788` to `magento 1.9.0.1`. Fixing your version should be analogous to my solution:

- add `SUPEE 3941` frist
- Also I needed to revert following modified files to original (copy them from downloaded `magento-1.9.0.1.tar.bz2`):

  app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php

  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php

  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php